# Render outside Graphics2D#create(Rectangle) area

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm trying to draw a image attached to a box, but:

```
Graphics2D surf = (Graphics2D) surface.create(x, y, width, height);
image.draw(surf, width, height);
surface.setColor(Color.BLUE);
surface.fillRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
surf.dispose();
```

doesnt render that box at -5 from the surface.create area

```
#creates a new Graphics object based on this Graphics object, but with a new translation and clip area.
```

how ignore clip area?

Comment: Use `surface.create(x - 5, y - 5, width, height);` and start rendering at 0x0...

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: MadProgrammer this will 'break' the anchor positional system.
Andrew Thompson, replacing x,y by any value will show that -5-5 will not be drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. the create does clip the area, the only simple solution I did is:

```
Graphics2D surf = (Graphics2D) surface.create();
surf.translate(x,y);
image.draw(surf, width, height);
surface.setColor(Color.BLUE);
surface.fillRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
surf.dispose();
```

And this does draw as expected.